# WPF Column set MIN height by dynamic margins?

Tags: .net, wpf, xaml, user-interface, grid-layout

Is it possible to set the minimum height of a row to be dynamic based on the content?  A brief explanation:

I have this piece of UI:
[image]

The whole thing is divided into a grid with two rows, one * height  where the top message is and the other "Auto" height where the bottom option buttons are.  This works great with full UI as it keeps the buttons stacked at the bottom where I want them and the text is in the top blank section centered where it should be.

However, when I make it small enough so not everything fits, it starts to cover over the message text and leaves the bottom buttons.  I can sent a min height on the top row and when the top row gets to that minimum size it starts cutting off the recent files which is livable as it will rarely get to that small, and removing the older recent files is not a big deal.

So the main issue is that the message can change based on the results of other code and it could be several lines or it could be just one line.  I can hard code the min height, but if I make it large enough to fit the longer messages there is a large margin around the one liners and if I fit the one liners it cuts off the longer ones.  Also since the text wraps, the height of the text message depends on the width of the window which is variable as well.  Is is possible to tell WPF that the minimum height of the row is the content height plus a margin?

If it's not possible I can definitely live with a hard coded height so don't spend a lot of time, but I thought it would be worth asking :)

Answer (score 1):

I would have the top row with `height=Auto` and the second row with `height=*` remembering to add `TextWrapping=Wrap` and add the margin to the first item/panel in the second row

eg simple example

```
<Grid Width="200">
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>            
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <TextBlock Text="some text in the top" TextWrapping="Wrap"></TextBlock>
    <ListBox Grid.Row="1" Margin="0,20"/>        
</Grid>
```

You would probably need a `ScrollViewer` wrapped around the `Grid` to cope with different size Windows

Comment: That may do it, but that would leave the white space at the bottom of the UI correct?  I would rather stack the lower portion all the way at the bottom and leave the white space at the top most of the time, but if the top gets to a minimum size it starts obscuring the bottom...